# updating a database through dataGridView

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview in c# and I am filling it with whatever table from my database I want, getting the table name from a textbox. everything is fine until I try to commit the changes I do in the datagridview to the database.

button2 is the button I will be using for update. I've searched all over and apparently updating the adapter should work, but it doesn't in this case and I can't figure out why. here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static string connstr = "DataSource=localhost;Database=sc2db;Trusted_Connection=True;";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select * from " + textBox1.Text, conn);
            adap.SelectCommand = comm;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            adap.Fill(dt);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            label1.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            adap.Update(dt);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            label1.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. my apologies, I am relatively new here.

Comment: I have written a post about this. may be this will help you http://yadavsachin.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/save-dataset-changes-to-database-in-c/

Answer (score 1):

Your `adap` in the button2_Click event handler doesn't have any Command (SelectCommand, DeleteCommand, InsertCommand and UpdateCommand) initialized. So how it can update?

You obviously don't understand how a DataAdapter works. The DataAdapter has 4 Command which are SelectCommand, DeleteCommand, InsertCommand, UpdateCommand. The `SelectCommand` is required for the method `Fill()` to work. Other commands are required for the method `Update()` works, of course in the general case which the DataRows can have all kinds of state: DataRowState.Deleted, DataRowState.Added, DataRowState.Modified. The `SelectCommand` is also required to build other commands automatically using a `CommandBuilder` (in SqlClient, that's `SqlCommandBuilder`). Once you pass a DataTable in the `Update()` method, all the rows in that table will be browsed through and the state of each DataRow will be checked to see if that row is added, deleted or modified and the adapter will call the corresponding Command (InsertCommand, DeleteCommand and UpdateCommand) it has to perform the actual operation to the database.

In your case, you can try declaring your `adap` as public and build other commands for it by using `SqlCommandBuilder` before calling the method `Update()` like this:

```
SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(adap);
```

Remember that using `SqlCommandBuilder()` will work only for single table in the Select query, if you have more than 1 table involved you have to build your own Commands for your DataAdapter. That's not difficult, you may want to search more about how to build commands for a DataAdapter.

I hope that helps you get started!

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlDataAdapter1);
            sqlDataAdapter1.Update(dataSetUser);
        }
```

im able to edit my database from gridview by this code